# Laravel boot method to delete relationship tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have the following boot method setup in my `user` model:

```
/**
 * Boot the model.
 *
 */
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($user)
    {
        $user->roles()->detach();
        $user->supervisors()->detach();
        $user->types()->detach();
        $user->rates()->detach();
        $user->miscs()->detach();
        $user->timesheets()->delete();
    });
}
```

A user can have many timesheets so I have a `hasMany` relationship setup for timesheets in the user model.

```
/**
 * The timesheets that belong to the user.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function timesheets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Timesheet\Timesheet');
}
```

A timesheet can also have many data, so I have added a relationship in the timesheet model:

```
/**
 * The data that belong to the timesheet.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function data()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Timesheet\DataTimesheet');
}
```

My question is, when I delete a user, it should delete the timesheet and all data associated with it.  At the moment, when I delete a user it deletes the user and the timesheet but not the data (DataTimesheet).

When I delete a timesheet separately, the data gets deleted.

**Can anyone suggest how I can delete the data as well when a user is deleted?**

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Because all this usually can be easily managed automatically by the DBMS by simply setting the right foreign keys in your database relationships

Comment: By DBMS what do you mean exactly? I am using MySQL and laravel migrations

Comment: Then when creating the migrations for your DB simple make all the user_id columns in all your tables (roles, supervisors, timesheets, ...) to be a [foreign key](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) pointing to the user.id column `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');`

Answer (score 1):

From the statement `When I delete a timesheet separately, the data gets deleted`, I am assuming you have a `deleting` event handled on the `Timesheet` model that deletes the data.

In order for your `deleting` event on the `Timesheet` model to get fired, a `Timesheet` instance has to be deleted. In your User `deleting` event, when you call `$user->timesheets()->delete();`, this bypasses the models and runs a query to delete the records. Because the Models are not being instantiated and deleted, the `deleting` events on your timesheet records are not being called.

In order to make sure your Timesheet events are called, you can do the following:

```
// get all the related timesheet ids
$ids = $user->timesheets()->lists('id');

// pass the ids to delete into the destroy method
\App\Models\Timesheet\Timesheet::destroy($ids);
```

The `destroy()` method will get a collection of the models for the ids and call `delete()` on each model, which will fire the events for each model.

Comment: Thanks for your help and reply. Does Laravel not have a built in function to delete pivot table data belonging to a specific relationship? It just seems an awkward and long winded way to do things.

Comment: @V4n1ll4 The point of having the cascading deletes at the application level is so that you can control the logic that goes into deleting the objects. If Laravel takes that over, you've lost that control, and you may as well have it coded at the database level. I suppose they could provide some type of default helper and let you override it, but they do not at this time. Maybe go to github and request the feature and see what they say.